# What's this strange notebook icon with a vertical line?

Tags: notebooks

Does anyone know what this icon means? I've tried searching, and I've tried creating one notebook of each type.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: Perhaps you should give your OS and version of MMA. Also what do you mean notebook of each type?

Comment: Thanks - Mac OS 10.15, Mathematica 12.1.1. As for types - if you go to file>new you get options for notebook, styled notebook, presenter notebook, Wolfram Alpha Mode Notbook, Wolfram Alpha Mode Presenter Notebook, and submenus for programmatic, package, and repository which have their own types.  Some of these produce files with the normal notebook icon, and some of them produce files with the greyed out icon like above, but without the vertical line down the middle.